# Laravel, when using Eloquent to retrieve data paginate and get methods are returning diferent output

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am having a hard time with Laravel. I have a query that returns all the table columns. The problem is that a field "foto" returns as an empty string in the JSON when I use the "get" or "find" methods. Paginate it works as expected.

This query:

```
$resultado = $query
           ->where('id_admin', '=', $id_admin)
           ->with('telasPermissao.itemPermissao')
           ->paginate(50);
```

`foto` comes as:

> ```
> "foto": "data/image:93483940349"
> ```

Now, with this:

```
$resultado = $query
           ->where('id_admin', '=', $id_admin)
           ->with('telasPermissao.itemPermissao')
           ->find(1);



$resultado = $query
           ->where('id_admin', '=', $id_admin)
           ->with('telasPermissao.itemPermissao')
           ->get(50);
```

`foto` comes as:

> ```
> "foto" : ""
> ```

I am returning the data from the controller like this:

```
return response()->json($resultado, 200);
```

In my operador model I have the following mutator:

```
public function getFotoAttribute($value)
{
    if ($value != null)
    {
        return pg_escape_string(fgets($value));
    }

        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your mutator like this:

```
public function getFotoAttribute()
{
    if ($this->attributes['foto'] != null)
    {
        return pg_escape_string(fgets($this->attributes['foto']));
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After fighting 2 hours, I give up. As a workoaround I used this to replace the find method.

```
      $resultado = $query->where('id_admin', '=', $id_admin)->with('telasPermissao.itemPermissao')->where('id', 517 )->paginate(1)
```

If someone knows what happened please post an answer.